# How to export SQL data to PDF download with Custom Design in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I'm newbie in Codeigniter and I need to export SQL data to PDF download with Custom Design. I searched in google and I only found the export as table. But I don't want to export like that. I want to export as below. It is my sample design to export.

[image]

Comment: use fpdf and html2pdf php library to create pdf using php. Here is the link https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf. might be help you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.